# Unknown Error : java.lang.RuntimeException android.os.Parcel.writeValue

Tags: java, android

I have gotten this error multiple times over the last couple of days in my app.  Since this is a bug report created by google, this is the whole stackTrace they provide.  The stack does not contain a reference to any of my created classes.  With that said I do not know where to start looking for the error and was hopping someone could lead me in the right direction.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.os.Parcel.writeValue (Parcel.java:1476)
  at android.os.Parcel.writeList (Parcel.java:811)
  at android.os.Parcel.writeValue (Parcel.java:1423)
  at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal (Parcel.java:723)
  at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner (BaseBundle.java:1408)
  at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel (Bundle.java:1133)
  at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle (Parcel.java:763)
  at android.app.FragmentState.writeToParcel (Fragment.java:147)
  at android.os.Parcel.writeTypedArray (Parcel.java:1306)
  at android.app.FragmentManagerState.writeToParcel (FragmentManager.java:381)
  at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable (Parcel.java:1495)
  at android.os.Parcel.writeValue (Parcel.java:1401)
  at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal (Parcel.java:723)
  at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner (BaseBundle.java:1408)
  at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel (Bundle.java:1133)
  at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle (Parcel.java:763)
  at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.activityStopped (ActivityManagerNative.java:3652)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$StopInfo.run (ActivityThread.java:3764)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:751)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:95)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:159)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6097)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:865)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

Comment: Are you using Parcelable in your project? And is there any place where you are sending Parcelable object via Bundle / Intent?

Comment: @hardartcore Yeas.  I use intent in various places in my project to initiate and pass information to new activities, start a service,  also to open google maps and to place a call directly from the app. I also use PendingIntent.

Comment: Do you send parcelable object using intents / bundle? Check those places where your Parcelable object has another parcelable or custom object.

Answer (score 0):

Its seems you pass with the intent same intent object.

Ex.

```
  Intent finishIntent  = new Intent(MainActivity.this, FinishActivity.class); 
  FinishData finishData = new FinishData();
```

This is wrong

```
 finish.putExtra(ConsKeys.KEY_FINISH_DATA, finishIntent);
```

This is true

```
 finish.putExtra(ConsKeys.KEY_FINISH_DATA, finishData);
```